# A maybe type in Python. Which implementation is best?

Tags: python

These are five implementations I’ve come up with for an equivalent for Haskell’s `Maybe` in Python. It’s not called `Optional` because `typing.Optional` already exists.

Here’s a simple monolithic class. The benefit of this one is that it can be inherited from:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Callable, Generic, Optional, TypeVar, cast, overload, Any

T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")
C = TypeVar("C", bound="Maybe[Any]")


class MissingValueError(ValueError):
    "Raised to indicate a potentially missing value was missing."
    pass


class Maybe(Generic[T]):
    present: bool
    value: Optional[T]

    @overload
    def __init__(self, /) -> None:
        ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self, value: T, /) -> None:
        ...

    def __init__(self, /, *args: T) -> None:
        if len(args) == 0:
            self.present = False
            self.value = None
        else:
            self.present = True
            self.value = args[0]

    @classmethod
    def Just(cls: type[C], value: T, /) -> C:
        return cls(value)

    @classmethod
    def Nothing(cls: type[C]) -> C:
        return cls()

    def assume_present(self) -> T:
        if not self.present:
            raise MissingValueError()
        return cast(T, self.value)

    def map(self: Maybe[T], f: Callable[[T], U], /) -> Maybe[U]:
        cls = type(self)
        if not self.present:
            return cls()
        else:
            return cls(f(cast(T, self.value)))

    def flatmap(self: Maybe[T], f: Callable[[T], Maybe[U]], /) -> Maybe[U]:
        cls = type(self)
        if not self.present:
            return cls()
        else:
            maybe2 = f(cast(T, self.value))
            if not maybe2.present:
                return cls()
            else:
                return cls(cast(U, maybe2.value))

    def join(self: Maybe[Maybe[T]], /) -> Maybe[T]:
        cls = cast(type[Maybe[T]], type(self))
        if not self.present:
            return cls()
        elif not cast(Maybe[T], self.value).present:
            return cls()
        else:
            return cls(cast(T, cast(Maybe[T], self.value).value))

    @classmethod
    def from_optional(cls: type[C], value: Optional[T], /) -> C:
        if value is None:
            return cls()
        else:
            return cls(value)

    @classmethod
    def with_bool(cls: type[C], /, present: bool, value: T) -> C:
        if present:
            return cls(value)
        else:
            return cls()
```

Here’s one where `Maybe` is an abstract base class from which `Just` and `Nothing` inherit.
It supports pattern matching and checking via `.present`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Callable, Generic, Optional, TypeVar, cast

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)
G = TypeVar("G")
U = TypeVar("U")


class Maybe(ABC, Generic[T]):
    present: bool
    value: Optional[T]

    @abstractmethod
    def assume_present(self) -> T:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def map(self: Maybe[G], f: Callable[[G], U], /) -> Maybe[U]:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def flatmap(self: Maybe[G], f: Callable[[G], Maybe[U]], /) -> Maybe[U]:
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def join(self: Maybe[Maybe[G]]) -> Maybe[G]:
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def from_optional(value: Optional[G], /) -> Maybe[G]:
        if value is None:
            return Nothing[G]()
        else:
            return Just[G](value)

    @staticmethod
    def with_bool(present: bool, value: G) -> Maybe[G]:
        if present:
            return Just[G](value)
        else:
            return Nothing[G]()


class Just(Maybe[T]):
    def __init__(self: Just[T], value: T) -> None:
        self.present = True
        self.value = value

    def assume_present(self: Just[G]) -> G:
        return cast(G, self.value)

    def map(self: Just[G], f: Callable[[G], U], /) -> Just[U]:
        return Just[U](f(cast(G, self.value)))

    def flatmap(self: Just[G], f: Callable[[G], Maybe[U]], /) -> Maybe[U]:
        return f(cast(G, self.value))

    def join(self: Just[Maybe[G]]) -> Maybe[G]:
        return cast(Maybe[G], self.value)

    __match_args__ = ("value",)


class MissingValueError(ValueError):
    "Raised to indicate a potentially missing value was missing."
    pass


class Nothing(Maybe[T]):
    def __init__(self: Nothing[T]) -> None:
        self.present = False
        self.value = None

    def assume_present(self: Nothing[G]) -> G:
        raise MissingValueError()

    def map(self: Nothing[G], f: Callable[[G], U], /) -> Nothing[U]:
        return Nothing[U]()

    def flatmap(self: Nothing[G], f: Callable[[G], Maybe[U]], /) -> Nothing[U]:
        return Nothing[U]()

    def join(self: Nothing[Maybe[G]]) -> Nothing[G]:
        return Nothing[G]()

    __match_args__ = ()
```

Here’s one that takes advantage of Python’s type system. It supports pattern matching and checking via `isinstance(`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Callable, TypeAlias, TypeVar, Generic, Optional

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)
G = TypeVar("G")
U = TypeVar("U")


@dataclass
class Nothing(Generic[T]):
    pass


@dataclass
class Just(Generic[T]):
    value: T


Maybe: TypeAlias = Nothing | Just[T]


def maybe_from_optional(value: Optional[G], /) -> Maybe[G]:
    if value is None:
        return Nothing[G]()
    else:
        return Just[G](value)


def maybe_with_bool(present: bool, value: G) -> Maybe[G]:
    if present:
        return Just[G](value)
    else:
        return Nothing[G]()


class MissingValueError(ValueError):
    "Raised to indicate a potentially missing value was missing."
    pass


def assume_present(maybe: Maybe[G], /) -> G:
    if isinstance(maybe, Nothing):
        raise MissingValueError
    return maybe.value


def map_maybe(f: Callable[[G], U], maybe: Maybe[G], /) -> Maybe[U]:
    if isinstance(maybe, Nothing):
        return Nothing[U]()
    else:
        return Just[U](f(maybe.value))


def flatmap_maybe(f: Callable[[G], Maybe[U]], maybe: Maybe[G], /) -> Maybe[U]:
    if isinstance(maybe, Nothing):
        return Nothing[U]()
    else:
        return f(maybe.value)
```

Here’s one where `Maybe` is a protocol that `Just` and `Nothing` implement.
Again, checking is done via pattern matching or `isinstance(`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Callable, Optional, TypeVar, cast, Protocol

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)
G = TypeVar("G")
U = TypeVar("U")


class Maybe(Protocol[T]):
    def assume_present(self) -> T:
        ...

    def map(self: Maybe[G], f: Callable[[G], U], /) -> Maybe[U]:
        ...

    def flatmap(self: Maybe[G], f: Callable[[G], Maybe[U]], /) -> Maybe[U]:
        ...

    def join(self: Maybe[Maybe[G]]) -> Maybe[G]:
        ...


class Just(Maybe[T]):
    value: T

    def __init__(self: Just[T], value: T) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def assume_present(self: Just[G]) -> G:
        return self.value

    def map(self: Just[G], f: Callable[[G], U], /) -> Just[U]:
        return Just[U](f(self.value))

    def flatmap(self: Just[G], f: Callable[[G], Maybe[U]], /) -> Maybe[U]:
        return f(self.value)

    def join(self: Just[Maybe[G]]) -> Maybe[G]:
        return self.value

    __match_args__ = ("value",)


class MissingValueError(ValueError):
    "Raised to indicate a potentially missing value was missing."
    pass


class Nothing(Maybe[T]):
    def __init__(self: Nothing[T]) -> None:
        self.present = False
        self.value = None

    def assume_present(self: Nothing[G]) -> G:
        raise MissingValueError()

    def map(self: Nothing[G], f: Callable[[G], U], /) -> Nothing[U]:
        return Nothing[U]()

    def flatmap(self: Nothing[G], f: Callable[[G], Maybe[U]], /) -> Nothing[U]:
        return Nothing[U]()

    def join(self: Nothing[Maybe[G]]) -> Nothing[G]:
        return Nothing[G]()

    __match_args__ = ()


def maybe_from_optional(value: Optional[G], /) -> Maybe[G]:
    if value is None:
        return Nothing[G]()
    else:
        return Just[G](value)


def maybe_with_bool(present: bool, value: G) -> Maybe[G]:
    if present:
        return Just[G](value)
    else:
        return Nothing[G]()
```

And finally, here’s a variant of the first monolithic one that uses a sentinel object instead of a `present` property:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Callable, Generic, Optional, TypeVar, cast, overload, Any

T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")
C = TypeVar("C", bound="Maybe[Any]")


class MissingValueError(ValueError):
    "Raised to indicate a potentially missing value was missing."
    pass


class Maybe(Generic[T]):
    sentinel = object()

    value: T | object

    @overload
    def __init__(self, /) -> None:
        ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self, value: T, /) -> None:
        ...

    def __init__(self, /, *args: T) -> None:
        if len(args) == 0:
            self.value = Maybe.sentinel
        else:
            self.value = args[0]

    @classmethod
    def Just(cls: type[C], value: T, /) -> C:
        return cls(value)

    @classmethod
    def Nothing(cls: type[C]) -> C:
        return cls()

    def assume_present(self) -> T:
        cls = type(self)
        if self.value is cls.sentinel:
            raise MissingValueError()
        return cast(T, self.value)

    def map(self: Maybe[T], f: Callable[[T], U], /) -> Maybe[U]:
        cls = type(self)
        if self.value is cls.sentinel:
            return cls()
        else:
            return cls(f(cast(T, self.value)))

    def flatmap(self: Maybe[T], f: Callable[[T], Maybe[U]], /) -> Maybe[U]:
        cls = type(self)
        if self.value is cls.sentinel:
            return cls()
        else:
            maybe2 = f(cast(T, self.value))
            if maybe2.value is cls.sentinel:
                return cls()
            else:
                return cls(cast(U, maybe2.value))

    def join(self: Maybe[Maybe[T]], /) -> Maybe[T]:
        cls = cast(type[Maybe[T]], type(self))
        if self.value is cls.sentinel:
            return cls()
        elif cast(Maybe[T], self.value).value is cls().sentinel:
            return cls()
        else:
            return cls(cast(T, cast(Maybe[T], self.value).value))

    @classmethod
    def from_optional(cls: type[C], value: Optional[T], /) -> C:
        if value is None:
            return cls()
        else:
            return cls(value)

    @classmethod
    def with_bool(cls: type[C], /, present: bool, value: T) -> C:
        if present:
            return cls(value)
        else:
            return cls()
```

Each of these function a bit differently, but they all broadly achieve the same thing—a `Maybe` type which can be a missing value or a present value, clearly distinguished. The monolithic ones have the benefit of being inheritable, although their typing is lacking as it does not represent the subclasses very well, as I know no way to accurately type methods of inheritable generic classes that change the parameter.

My questions: Which of these do you think is the best, and do you think there are any clear improvements that can be made to each one?

---

As I have been asked for a use-case for this, I will present the catalyst for me trying to implement this:

I was trying to generate random `Signature` objects using the Hypothesis library. `Signature` objects are composed of a list of `Parameter` objects subject to a number of conditions. To implement the generation, I ended up using a `@composite` search strategy that draws random lists of each of the parameters needed to construct a `Parameter` object. As part of this, I wanted to generate default values, and needed to distinguish between the absence of a default value for a parameter and the presence of one that is `None`. Unfortunately, generating `Parameter.empty()`, which is used internally by `Parameter`, as one of the parameters to `Parameter` didn’t work.
In the end, I went with generating a one-off sentinel object and checking identity on it, but I find this solution to be less than satisfying. Because of this, I decided to try and implement a `Maybe` type in Python.

Comment: As you did not present a use case for either implementation, I'd say that they are all equally useless.

Comment: That's a little harsh, but still: I do hope that this is strictly academic or recreational, because this should not be done in a professional setting.

Comment: yeah it is. Although I would claim this could be useful in some cases, but I'd like to hear your argument against this.

Comment: FWIW my comment was not meant to be hash, but a tongue-in-cheek pun. At any rate, for a review it'd be good to know how this is supposed to be used in project.

Comment: I have added a real-world use-case.